# Add milliseconds to current time

Tags: swift

So I currently have a now playing swift app, that requests to the server every 30 seconds, and seems to be overloading the server.

Since we request data from iTunes API about the current song that is playing, I was thinking that I could possibly limit the request if a result was found by iTunes API.

Using `trackTimeMillis` I could add that trackTimeMillis to the current time and if not greater than the time don't ping the server. If greater than ping server for latest track.

I am thinking I will need to wrap the function that pings the server in a

```
Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: Date(), to: Date()), diff > Date())+ trackTimeMillis {
```

But that does not work

basically I need to add trackTimeMillis to the current Date() and if that users current timestamp (date) is larger than the `Date() + trackTimeMillis` then allow request.

Comment: "need to add trackTimeMillis to the current Date()" So do that. Convert to a double, divide by 1000, and add directly to the date.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do with the code snippet you put in your question.

Focusing on how you add some number of milliseconds to a `Date()`:

Date has the function `addingTimeInterval(_:)`

If you need to add a certain number of milliseconds do a date, use this:

```
newDate = Date().addingTimeInterval( Double(millis) / 1000)
```

---

### Edit:

As Matt pointed out, you can do that even more simply by writing

```
newDate = Date() + Double(millis) / 1000
```

Since there is an override of the `+` operator that takes a `Date` and a `Double` and returns a `Date`.

Both versions of this add a `Double` containing a specified number of **seconds** to the Date. Since `Double`s can represent very small and very large numbers you can add or subtract values ranging from tiny fractions of a second to thousands of years to any `Date`.

---

Comment: No need for addingTimeInterval.  You can literally just use +.

Comment: Cool. It makes sense that there would be an override on the "+" operator for `Date` and `Double`/`TimeInterval`.

Comment: Personally I avoid using this `+` override and recommend `addingTimeInterval`. While it's obvious to folks who have a long Cocoa history, it's not obvious to newcomers what `Date() + 1` means. Just looking at it, it looks like it adds one day. Coming from other languages, it's common for the "default" unit to be ms (and I've seen a lot of bugs around that, and the OP seems to be of that school). While we do have to teach people "TimeInterval is always seconds," at least seeing the word "TimeInterval" IMO is useful in avoiding common bugs. (But I see where others might disagree here.)

Comment: @RobNapier, fair point. It's especially confusing if you add integer values to a Date. Those of us who've been programming in Cocoa forever (And those who go back even longer, to NextStep) won't be confused, but others might.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler alternative. When I am doing a task like this, I usually store the `Date` of the previous request, e.g.:

```
let lastRequestTime = Date()
```

and then simply check the elapsed time:

```
if Date().timeIntervalSince(lastRequestTime) > 30 {
  ...
}
```

Another option is to use `Timer`. Basically, you can schedule a `Timer` that will send the request after X seconds. If you receive a response from a different source first, you simply cancel the `Timer` and possibly the request if it is already running.